# How to add buffer portion to media player?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to save media files to be cached while the player is playing. 
While the player to play the first part - the file is loaded:

```
  public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {
        URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
        path=mediaUrl;
        cn.connect();
        sizef=cn.getContentLength();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
        }

        downloadingMediaFile = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia.dat");

        // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or something, we also delete any previously 
        // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh.  If you use this code, always delete 
        // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk memory.  Of course, you can also 
        // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for instant replay if you wanted as well.
        if (downloadingMediaFile.exists()) {
            downloadingMediaFile.delete();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
        byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
        int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);   
            if (numread <= 0)   
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            totalBytesRead += numread;
            incrementalBytesRead += numread;
            totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

            testMediaBuffer();
            //fireDataLoadUpdate();
        } while (validateNotInterrupted());   
            stream.close();
        if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
           //   fireDataFullyLoaded();
        }
    }
```

But when buffer is bigger than 4mb i try to transfer buffer to media player:

```
private void  testMediaBuffer() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                    try { 
                        //mUri=Uri.parse(path);
                        openVideo();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);               
                    }
                }
            } else if ((totalKbRead - pfile) >= 4000){ 
                //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}
```

But when i do transfer buffer file to player  - he drop the sound and video.
I tried different combinations, but best result drops video and audio. How correct add new portion of buffer???

```
 private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
        try { 
            // First determine if we need to restart the player after transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
            boolean wasPlaying = mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();


            // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.  Store the old File for deleting later. 
            File oldBufferedFile = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
            File bufferedFile = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");

            //  This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on exit.  If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything.  If you want to 
            // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write caching code and please send me a copy.
            bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();   
            moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

            // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start a new one.  So far (Android v1.5),
            // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've stopped the player and started a new one
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            int curPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //mMediaPlayer.release();
            //mMediaPlayer=null;
            // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior one.

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bufferedFile);

            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            //mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            /*if (mAudioSession != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(mAudioSession);
            } else {
                mAudioSession = mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
            }
            setListeners();*/
            pfile=bufferedFile.length()/1024;

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            //mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface (sf));
           // mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            // we don't set the target state here either, but preserve the
            // target state that was there before.
           // mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARING;
            //attachMediaController();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);
            //mMediaPlayer.start(); 
            //  Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was previously playing.  
            //  NOTE:  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
            //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
            /*boolean atEndOfFile = (totalKbRead - pfile) >= 1000;
            if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            }*/

            // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no longer needed.
            oldBufferedFile.delete();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error -------------------------------------------------------", e);                    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my mediaplayer to vitamio media player (https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) and try to solving many new issues (https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues)))